# How has SoundCloud done that?

Tags: html

Their UI is pure HTML, CSS and JS, so how they're playing the audio?
Involving a hidden flash player?

Comment: Please see [this great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12271972/1004889) fellow SC engineer @nickf gave to [a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263672/how-is-soundcloud-player-programmed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The embed code for their demo video looks like this:

```
<object width="400" height="250"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?
    clip_id=1857085&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;
    show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1" />
<embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=1857085&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=&amp;fullscreen=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="400" height="250"></embed></object><p><a href="http://vimeo.com/1857085">SoundCloud: The Tour</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/soundcloud">SoundCloud</a> on <a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```

Blah blah blah. The .swf extension is the giveaway.  It's Adobe Flash.

Comment: But how they done the connection between the HTML buttons(like play, pause, seek...) and the swf file?

Comment: The buttons are most likely part of the programming in the .swf file itself.

Comment: @melee: There could be a number of reasons for that. The most likely one is that you are being served up a custom mobile page instead of the usual one.

Comment: Guess I need to spoof my browser and see their HTML5 ways, haha

Comment: Its possible to interact with flash objects via javascript. The flash object effectively presents an API that the JS can interact with to do things like start and stop.

Comment: @Chris: I think melee's point is that Flash won't run on the IPad.

Comment: @robert Harvey: I was actually replying to really old comments before I realised that this was a resurrection of an old thread. My comments were meant to be aimed at Adir who was asking how the html and swf interacted.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently they use Sound Manager 2, a flash player with Javascript controls.

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Answer (score 1):

The darkening is actually automatic and handled by soundmanager2

Answer (score 0):

It's using a sort-of 'lightbox'-like script, checkout the link below for a demo:
http://videobox-lb.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Not quite guys, their audio player is indeed pure html and is quite clever really. They generate a waveform image server side when the audiofile is uploaded, construct a player with standard html widgets and use AJAX calls to move the play head and also darken the waveform as the audio is buffering.

Here you can see an example, if you look at this in firebug you will see the width attribute is constantly changing to move it forward as it plays..

```
<div class="playhead" style="width: 32.75630235388422%;"></div>
```

Alex..

Comment: AJAX? I don't think so, this is too fast to be AJAX(try it yourself)

Comment: For the playhead you are probably right, but the waveform darkening is definitely AJAX.